# How to control a constant hot water outlet temperature for a heat exchanger?

Tags: modelica

Now the temperature of the water supply is only 40 degrees Celsius, which is not the 50 degrees Celsius that I want. The heat exchanger water temperature should reach 50 degrees Celsius.

What control method should be used?

Can it only be achieved by increasing control

[image]